# How to identify 'Merge Call' and 'Add Call' with BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

Is there a way in Android to find "Add Call", "Merge Call" events. In case of call disconnect ("TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK"), how to identify which call/number got disconnected ?